# Loop over array of objects in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am creating an array of objects in jQuery.

```
var selected_tests = $("#selected_tests").find("tr");
jsonLab = [];
$.each(selected_tests, function() {
  jsonLab.push({
    test: ($(this).children()).eq(0).text(),
    amount: ($(this).children()).eq(1).text()
  });
});
```

I am posting this array to a PHP file by

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="jsonLab"/>').val(jsonLab).appendTo('#bill_print');
$("#bill_print").submit();
```

In my PHP file

```
if(isset($_POST['jsonLab']))
{
  $lab = json_decode($_POST['jsonLab'],true);
  foreach ($lab as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["test"] . ", " . $value["amount"] . "<br>";
  }   
}
```

There seems to be some mistake in the way I am using `foreach` or maybe it's incorrectly formatted JSON which isn't being decoded by PHP. I dont want to use AJAX for the submission.

Comment: Have you done any logging to see what `$_POST['jsonLab']` is or what your `$value` are?

Comment: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Try `stringify`ing your array before setting it to the hidden field.

Comment: @TiiJ7 , stringify did the job , Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with this call:

```
.val(jsonLab)
```

`jsonLab` is an array of objects held in JS. As such, setting it to the `val()` of a jQuery object will mean `toString()` is called on it. The result of that is `[object Object]`. This is what's sent to your PHP logic, hence the error.

To fix this you need to manually stringify the JSON when you set it to the value of the text field:

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="jsonLab" />').val(JSON.stringify(jsonLab)).appendTo('#bill_print');
```

Also note that you can use a single `map()` call on the `#selected_tests tr` elements instead of selecting then pushing to an explicitly instantiated array:

```
var jsonLab = $("#selected_tests tr").map(function() {
  return {
    test: $(this).children().eq(0).text(),
    amount: $(this).children().eq(1).text()
  };
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks mate , JSON.stringify solved it , i will take your map suggestion aswell

Comment: No problem glad to help.